# If/else when reading array in Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a like button, that needs to check if the post is liked by the user. Trying to do something like this:

1. Check if user liked: set state to true
2. If user have not liked, state remains false
3. If user clicks on like, set to true and write to Firestore

I tried using array-contains, but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      liked: false,
    }
  }
    like = () => {

    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    let uid;

    const usersRef = firestore.collection("tips").doc(this.props.post)

    usersRef.then((docSnapshot) => {
      if ("likes", "array-contains", user.uid) {
          this.setState({
            liked: !this.state.liked
          })
      } else {
        usersRef.update({
          likes: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(user.uid)
        })
        this.setState({
          liked: !this.state.liked
        })
      }
    });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: How does an `if` block work like that? Shouldn't you use `where` to query? I don't know Firebase but the documentation says to query an array like that you should use `where`. Then, according to the result get back you can set your logic in an `if/else` block.

Comment: @devserkan Yes, I know it is possible to use `.where("likes", "array-contains", user.uid)`, but how can I get that in an if/else block?

Comment: I don't know what the query returns but after getting the result back, you can set up a logic according to this returned result right? `if (result) { do something} else { do another thing }`